# why I am getting error while taking input for variable b.(8th line)

Tags: c++, runtime-error

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    long long a;
    long long b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    long long n = s.length();
    long long y = 1;
    while (s[n - a] - 48 == 0)
        y++;
    vector<long long> v;
    long long c = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < n - y; i++) {
        long long x = s[i] - 48;
        if (c < a) {
            c = c * 10;
            c += x;
        }
        c = c % a;
        if (c == 0 && s[i + 1] != '0') {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    cout << v[0] << endl;
    for (long long j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {
        c = 0;
        for (long long i = v[j] + 1; i < n; i++) {
            long long x = s[i] - 48;
            if (c < b) {
                c = c * 10;
                c += x;
            }
            c = c % b;
        }
        if (c == 0) {
            cout << "YES" << endl;
            cout << s.substr(0, v[j] + 1) << endl
                 << s.substr(v[j] + 1, n - v[j] - 1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "NO";
}
```

- Testcase 
  39915186055525904358
  90102  63169402
  Other testcases are working fine except above one. till line 7 coding is working fine. but while taking input for "b" code is getting dumped.
  https://codeforces.com/contest/490/my. The last submission. I am getting Runtime error on 19th testcase.

Comment: 1) `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Use the proper headers, not this one.  2)  If you have a test case, then put that data in the code.  There is no need for `cin` statements.

Comment: Please describe what this code suppose to do!

Comment: Is "Testcase 39915186055525904358 90102 63169402" the input that fails?

Comment: `while (s[n - a] - 48 == 0) y++;` Negative index if `a > n`. Also, possible infinite loop if `s[n-a]-48 != 0`

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?  And why not try the code on a compiler installed on your computer?  If you did that, the error would be obvious, given the answer(s) below.

Comment: The link `https://codeforces.com/contest/490/my` only works when *you* are logged in.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming "Testcase 39915186055525904358 90102 63169402" is the input that fails, you got the following scenario:

```
cin >> s; // reads "Testcase"
cin >> a; // reads 39915186055525904358 
cin >> b; // reads 90102
```

Then in

```
while (s[n - a] - 48 == 0) y++;
```

the index you try to access is negative, which causes a segmentation fault.

Also that's an endless loop, because you never modify, `s`, `n` or `a`.

---

If "Testcase" is just a prefix and the actual testing data is just "39915186055525904358 90102 63169402" then `s` is "39915186055525904358" and `a` will be `90102`, which is still way more than the length of `s`.

Comment: Thanks!! This was the error.

Comment: Probably the "Testcase" part does not belong to the input. Reading `39915186055525904358` for `a` would fail since it is too large for `long long` and the following input line wouldn't do anything since `cin` would be in `fail` state.

Comment: tl;dr sanitise your inputs